# Access is denied: 'DundasWebChart' in SSRS 2000

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2000, dundas

I keep getting the following exception in SQL Server 2000 reports

> Exception of type Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.ReportRenderingException was thrown. (rrRenderingError) Get Online Help
>
> Exception of type Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.ReportRenderingException was thrown.
>               Access is denied: 'DundasWebChart'.

This is only happening when I have reports with graphs. 
Enable anonymous access  in IIS is disabled.
Please let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: Eek, SSRS *2000*? No chance of upgrading, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I will accept this as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Good to hear you resolved the issue! You can probably best write an answer yourself, explain a few more details on why SSRS 2000 *really* did not work. That's more helpful to future visitors than just my comment :) You can accept your own answer after 24hrs I believe.